# Analysis of algorithm and finding its time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> if T(n) = n √ n then
>
> 1. T(n) = O(n)
> 2. T(n) = O(n log n)
> 3. T(n) = O(n^2)
> 4. None of the above

Which of the above options is correct? How to find the order in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is O(n^1.5).

O(n) < O(n log n) < O(n^1.5) < O(n^2).

So answer is 4.